# Sales Revenue per product from sales/order

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, filter, sales, reports

I need to get **the sales revenue per product using sales order.**

I have been using `product_collection` to multiply `FinalPrice` with `order_qty`
But as the `FinalPrice` changes, this is no good to work out the actual sales revenue.

I can get the revenue for all products but I cannot seem to filter by Product ID.

```
$revenue = Mage::getModel( 'sales/order' )->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('grand_total')
            ->getColumnValues('grand_total');

$overall_profit = array_sum( $revenue );
$overall_profit = Mage::helper( 'core' )->currency( $overall_profit, true, false );
```

I am using this inside a loop so I have access to `Product_ID`, `SKU` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your own answer, you can do it using Magento objects as Julien suggested:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $prodId);

$collection->getSelect()
    ->from('sales_flat_order_item', 
         array('sum' => 'sum(sales_flat_order_item.row_total_incl_tax)'
    );

$productRevenue= 0;

foreach($collection as $result) {
     $productRevenue += $result->getSum();
}

$productRevenue = $productRevenue / 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom function I wrote to calculate the bestselling products (top 5) for a particular store... you should be able to modify it to get the data you need.

```
/**
 * Create a collection of products based directly on the sales items
 *
 * @return Varien_Data_Collection
 */
protected function _directSalesCollection()
{
    $this->setData('direct', true);

    /* @var $read Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface */
    $read       = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    $select     = new Varien_Db_Select($read);
    $collection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
    $result     = array();

    $select->from(
        array('i' => Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getResource()->getMainTable()),
        array(
            'product_id'    => 'i.product_id',
            'product_name'  => 'i.name',
            'total_sales'   => 'SUM(i.base_price)',
            'product_price' => 'AVG(i.base_price)',
            'qty_ordered'   => 'SUM(i.qty_ordered)',
        )
    )
    ->join(
        array('o' => Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getResource()->getMainTable()),
        'i.order_id = o.entity_id',
        array()
    )
    ->where('o.state NOT IN(?)', array('closed', 'canceled'))
    ->where('o.store_id = ?', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->where('o.created_at >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)')
    ->group('i.product_id')
    ->order('total_sales '. Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC)
    ->limit(5);

    $rows = $read->fetchAll($select);

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $collection->addItem(new Varien_Object($row));
    }

    return $collection;
}
```

For that function, I was less considered about the total sales amount. If you want the actual sold price you can use `i.base_row_total` instead of `i.base_price`. Of course this does NOT include values for tax or shipping... if you need tax to be included use `i.base_row_total_incl_tax` but shipping cannot and should not be included for the product level report.

Answer (score 0):

OK I managed to do it with this SQL Query:

```
$query = "SELECT sum(row_total_incl_tax) FROM sales_flat_order_item where product_id = $prod_id";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);   
$fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$product_revenue = array_sum($fetch);
$product_revenue = $product_revenue/2;
```

I had to divide the result by two and I got the correct figure, checked manually.

Comment: Please use Magento objects for manipulate collections rather than pure SQL and basic PHP functions to achieve what you need.

Comment: If it was possible I would have :)

Comment: How is it not possible?

Comment: With my limited knowledge of the subject. You could have demonstrated it and got the extra rep points but looks like someone beat you too it :)

Comment: No worries man, I was simply trying to avoid you some trouble, I don't really have an answer to your question, your use of pure SQL and basic functions just struck me that's all :)

Answer (score 0):

@mike

you can try below query with `groupby`

```
$query = "SELECT sum(row_total_incl_tax) FROM sales_flat_order_item where product_id = $prod_id groupby product_id" ;
```

This will return you a total of that product so you don't have to use `array_sum` function this will return you a single row.